# Can't make different pages into one depending user button selection ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to load a component depending in what page are the user.

Pages:

- Executables
- Shop

In the main screen I have a sidebar with 2 icons that i want the primary button sets the Executables Page and the second shop page.
Like having a web page with no routes and rendering components depending the user selection.

My code:

`Components/Dashboard.tsx`

```js
import styled from "styled-components"
import Executable from "./Executable"
import Navbar from "./Navbar"

import { useEffect } from "react"

type EntryProps = {
  section: string
}

const Dashboard = ({ section }: EntryProps) => {
  var TypeElement
  useEffect(() => {
    if (section === "executables") {
      TypeElement = (
        <div className="grid">
          <div className="row">
            <Executable />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }, [section])

  return (
    <Section>
      <Navbar />
      {TypeElement}
    </Section>
  )
}
```

`Components/Sidebar.tsx`

```js
import styled from "styled-components"
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa"
import { BsFileEarmarkBinary } from "react-icons/bs"
import { BiLogOut } from "react-icons/bi"
import { AiOutlineShoppingCart } from "react-icons/ai"
import { IoMdSettings } from "react-icons/io"

import { useState } from "react"

type SidebarProps = {
  section: string
  setSection: Function
}

const Sidebar = ({ section, setSection }: SidebarProps) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true)
  const handleDisabled = () => setDisabled(!disabled)

  return (
    <Aside id="aside">
      <div
        className={disabled ? "brand center" : "brand"}
        onClick={handleDisabled}
      >
        <FaBars />
      </div>
      <ul className="links">
        <li>
          <BsFileEarmarkBinary />
          <span
            className={disabled ? "disabled" : ""}
            onClick={(e) => {
              console.log("Executables")
              setSection("executables")
            }}
          >
            Executables
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <AiOutlineShoppingCart />
          <span
            className={disabled ? "disabled" : ""}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              setSection("shop")
            }}
          >
            Shop
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <IoMdSettings />
          <span
            className={disabled ? "disabled" : ""}
            onClick={setSection("settings")}
          >
            Settings
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div className="logout">
        <BiLogOut />
      </div>
    </Aside>
  )
}
```

`Pages/DashboardPage.tsx`

```js
import styled from "styled-components"

// Components
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar"
import Rightsidebar from "../components/Rightsidebar"
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard"

import { useState } from "react"

const DashboardPage = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState("executables")

  const setSection = (name: string) => {
    setPage(name)
  }
  
  return (
    <Div>
      <Sidebar section={page} setSection={setSection} />
      <Dashboard section={page} />
      <Rightsidebar />
    </Div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the value of TypeElement conditionally according to the value of the section. TypeElement is not a state, so after changing the value of the TypeElement component is not rerendered, and the updated value is not showing on the UI. Here conditional rendering might be a good solution.

```
<Section>
      <Navbar />
      {section==='executables'?  <Executable />: <Shop/>}
</Section>
```